# Syntax/Railroad diagrams in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I'm trying to draw Syntax diagrams in LaTeX. I've tried both [rail](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rail) and [syngen](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/syngen). However I can't get either to build properly. Are there any more modern alternatives?

Comment: See section 5 Tutorial: Diagrams as Simple Graphs of the TikZ manual for a start.

Comment: Before this can be reopened I think more details need to be added describing both what you have tried and what you want to do -- the term "syntax diagram" is far too vague.

Comment: @Andrew: railroad diagram is *very* specific, however. Example? The SQLite documentation has a great number of these to explain the syntax. They are really well suited to understand syntax: https://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html

Comment: Your question does not mention "railroad diagrams"? In any case, if you can reword your question to explain what you want, rather than referring to an external link which may exist year, we can try to help.

Comment: @Andrew: it's not my question. I was remarking on your comment. Have a nice weekend! :)

Comment: @Andrew "Syntax Diagrams" and "Railroad Diagrams" are both technical terms that are used interchangeably. Please see - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram. I don't know how much more specific the question could be.

Comment: This question seems perfectly clear to me. I feel it should be reopened.